# React is expected to be globally available

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs, reactjs

I'm playing with React (@13.3) with babel and webpack.

I have a component that's defined like this:

```
import BaseComponent from './BaseComponent';

export default class SomeComponent extends BaseComponent {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                    <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/900/600"/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

But I get the following error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: React is not defined

I understand the error: the JSX bit is compiled into `React.createElement(...)` but `React` isn't in the current scope since it's not imported.

My questions is:
What's the clean way to work around this issue? Do I have to somehow expose `React` globally with webpack?

---

Solution used:

I followed @salehen-rahman suggestion.

In my webpack.config.js:

```
module: {
    loaders: [{
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'react-hot!babel?plugins[]=react-require'
    }, {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loader: 'style!css!autoprefixer?browsers=last 2 versions'
    }]
},
```

I also needed to fix my tests, so I added this to the file helper.js:

```
require('babel-core/register')({
    ignore: /node_modules/,
    plugins: ['react-require'],
    extensions: ['.js']
});
```

My tests are then launched with the following command:

```
mocha --require ./test/helper.js 'test/**/*.js'
```

Comment: Have you tried `import React from 'react';`?

Comment: import React should be in the BaseComponent.

Comment: @JanakaStevens it doesn't matter. The above code should still not run, considering how either React wasn't manually imported, or there isn't any transformer involved that would automatically import React.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> My questions is : What's the clean way to work around this issue ? Do I have to somehow expose React globally with webpack ?

Add [`babel-plugin-react-require`](https://github.com/vslinko/babel-plugin-react-require) to your project, and then amend your webpack's Babel config to have settings akin to:

```
loaders: [
  {
    test: /.js$/,
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    loader: 'babel-loader',
    query: {
      stage: 0,
      optional: ['runtime'],
      plugins: [
        'react-require' // <-- THIS IS YOUR AMENDMENT
      ]
    },
  }
]
```

Now, once you've applied the configuration update, you can initialize React components without manually importing React.

```
React.render(
  <div>Yippee! No <code>import React</code>!</div>,
  document.body // <-- Only for demonstration! Do not use document.body!
);
```

Bear in mind though, `babel-plugin-react-require` transforms your code to automatically include React imports **only** in the presence of JSX tag in a *specific* file, *for* a specific file. For every other file that don't use JSX, but needs React for whatever reason, you will have to manually import React.

Comment: Works for me, I added some more pointers to the original post. Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

If you have react in your node modules directory you can add `import React from 'react';` at the top of your file.

Comment: I could do that, but it feels weird to have an import that's not actually used after. Well it is, but not directly by me :/.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Webpack's `ProvidePlugin`. To use, update the plugins section in your Webpack config to include the following:

```js
plugins: [
  new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    'React': 'react'
  })
]
```

This, however, doesn't solve it for the tests..