# How to make react available on whole app without importing it again and again in every jsx file

Tags: reactjs, webpack, jsx

How to make react available on the whole app without importing it again and again in every jsx file using webpack

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32553491/react-is-expected-to-be-globally-available/32556581#32556581).

Answer (score 3):

Using the `ProvidePlugin`. Docs: https://webpack.github.io/docs/shimming-modules.html

But just so we have code here, add this to `plugins`:

```
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
  React: "react",
})
```

This essentially does a `require('react')` and makes the result a global variable called `React`, which is accessible for all modules.

See more options in this answer: [Webpack ProvidePlugin vs externals?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23305599/webpack-provideplugin-vs-externals)

Comment: First link is broken (due to webpack1 docs being deleted)